# How to find and count number of matches in an array of objects for a 4 digit number with MongoDB (i.e. lottery numbers)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I'm creating some sort of lottery game where users can submit a 4 digit number between numbers 1-9 (e.g. "1, 4, 5, 8"). Then the game concludes with a winning 4 digit number using Math.random.

What I need to do is find the number of matches for each user and determine who among them got 1 match, 2 matches, 3 matches, and 4 matches.

Example:

- Winning numbers - 1, 2, 3, 4
- User: Josh (**1**, **2**, 7, 9 got 2 matches)
- User: Ryan (**4**, **3**, **1**, 6 got 3 matches)
- User: Angelo (5, 6, 7, 9 got 0 matches)

How do I do this with MongoDB aggregate? It should return how many matches each user made, I'm not exactly sure what to do.

Option #1: Maybe adding a new field on each of the object would make sense? Maybe like this:

```
"name": "Josh",
"lotteryNumber": "1279",
"matchesMade": 2
```

Option #2: Maybe do 5 queries? 1 for 0 match, 1 for 1 match, 1 for 2 match, and so on?

Here's a link to mongo playground with the collection included: https://mongoplayground.net/p/_uK3a7U3g0X

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ Besides, there are a lot of ambiguities. Are the numbers 3 digits or 4 digits? What should be the expected output for your example? and why your example is different from the one in the playground? Without resolving these, I don't think anyone can help

Comment: oh sorry about this. editing now.

Comment: @ray, i edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you look for something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $match: {
  "entries.lotteryNumber": {
    $in: [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
   }
  }
 },
{
 "$addFields": {
  "entries": {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$entries",
      "as": "e",
      "in": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$e",
          {
            lotteryMatchingCount: {
              $size: {
                "$setDifference": [
                  "$$e.lotteryNumber",
                  {
                    "$setDifference": [
                      "$$e.lotteryNumber",
                      [
                        1,
                        2,
                        3
                      ]
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
])
```

Assumption:
Best if you have the numbers as array to be easier in mongoDB , not a best practice to keep number as strings ( Also not sure why users are in entries array and not in single document( single document has limit of 16MB in mongoDB , if you have 20M users to apply to the lottery ? )
( Not very clear what exact final result need to looks like , perhaps if you provide more details I can adjust accordingly? )

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7kqTTH_guwh)

Explained:

1. Match only documents that contain at least one of the matching lottary numbers. ( reduce the amount of documents for enxt stage , you can remove this stage if you need to get all documents modified showing the count of matches )
2. Walk over the users inside entries and claculate the count ot matching lottary number inside new variable called "lotteryMatchingCount"

Comment: You mean keep each number as an array item, so if it's a 4 digit number, the array would contain 4 items [1, 2, 3, 4]? I see, got it. I went with embedding because I only have like 50 users that will play. If I make each lottery entry a single document, does that mean I should have a separate collection for lottery entries, and then a collection for the lottery itself (with lottery id, date started, and stuff), then I just reference the entries with it?

Comment: On top of @R2D2's idea, I would suggest denormalizing the documents into `entries` level to keep them as individual documents. `matchesMade` can be computed using a similar idea to R2D2 like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3RobtloV1yo)

Comment: @user874737 only 50 users not an issue at all you can keep them  in a single document , but indeed the professional way is as per #ray proposal -> denormalized & intersection instead of double-diff ...