# Count number of matching elements between two arrays with MongoDB filter

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I need to count the number of matching elements between 2 arrays using MongoDB filter aggregation. I tried using $eq and $setIntersection on the condition field of filter but the number of matching elements return just **1** even if all 4 elements match.

Here's the user scenario:

1. User enters 4 digit number: **1, 2, 3, 4**
2. It should check the number of matches it has with the numbers on the backend. In this case, **1, 2, 3, 4** also.
3. Should return **4** matches.

Right now, it's just returning 1 on my query. If there's a mismatch, like the user enters **1, 2, 3, 5** then it should return **3** matches.

Here's the query:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $match: {
    "entries.numbers": {
      $in: [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  "$addFields": {
    "matchingCount": {
      $size: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$entries",
          as: "e",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$e.numbers",
              [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Here's the playground link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/5YSDOL6LwGs

Comment: Might need `$reduce`

Comment: It is because you are keeping the entries in sub array level. You will need to iterate through the array like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FHz5yYp8uVZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Wrt

> *but the number of matching elements return just 1 even if all 4 elements match.*

If you remove the `$size` part from the `$addFields` stage, you'll see that `matchingCount` is actually a list of one object, so `$size` returns 1.

```js
"matchingCount": [
  {
    "name": "Josh",
    "numbers": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
  }
]
```

Also, changing the order of `[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]` anywhere in the pipeline or the gives no match at all. So you really should just be using sets.

**2.** In [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77504645/1431750), you've [given an example db](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_uK3a7U3g0X) where all other `entries` are together in one document, as an array of objects.

So if you want all the matching entries which have **at least one correct guess**:

Input collection, with order of numbers being different from the "winning" `[1, 2, 3, 4]`:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "1234",
    "entries": [
      {"name": "Josh", "numbers": [4, 1, 3, 2]},
      {"name": "only three", "numbers": [1, 2, 3, 5]},
      {"name": "none", "numbers": [9, 8, 7, 6]}  // no matches
    ]
  }
]
```

Query:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$entries" },
  {
    // separated for clarity
    $addFields: {
      intersect: {
        $setIntersection: [
          "$entries.numbers",
          [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // remove docs which have no match
    $match: {
      intersect: { $ne: [] }
    }
  },
  {
    // can be combined with the stage above
    $addFields: {
      matchingCount: { $size: "$intersect" }
    }
  },
  {
    // if you only want guesses with at least three matches
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gte: [
          // change this two whatever you want
          "$matchingCount",
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [ "fields", "you", "don't", "want" ]
  }
])
```

Result with my example db:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "1234",
    "entries": { "name": "Josh", "numbers": [ 4, 1, 3, 2 ] },
    "intersect": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
    "matchingCount": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": "1234",
    "entries": { "name": "only three", "numbers": [ 3, 5, 1, 2 ] },
    "intersect": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    "matchingCount": 3
  }
]
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hgrbpj9g2x-)

And here's a combined-stages version of that, along with
[the playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qX3YJlvDoNU):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$entries" },
  {
    // can be combined with the stage above
    $addFields: {
      matchingCount: {
        $size: {
          $setIntersection: [
            "$entries.numbers",
            [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // if you only want guesses with at least three matches
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gte: [
          // change this two whatever you want
          "$matchingCount",
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "entries.numbers": { $in: [1, 2, 3, 4] }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      matchingNumbers: {
        $setIntersection: ["$entries.numbers", [1, 2, 3, 4]]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      matchingCount: { $size: "$matchingNumbers" }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Did _you_ try this query? Even with the base input of just one entry for `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, the result has: `{ "matchingCount": 0, "matchingNumbers": [] }`. [Mongo Playground of this solution with best-case input](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q6KdmJixQaf)